# Determining average i/o file size on my computer

Tags: ssd, benchmarking, io

I'd like to see what the average data size is that my computer reads and writes to the hard drive.  Many of the SSD benchmarks assume a 4K block of data, but what is my workload averages 16K?  How will that impact performance?

Any suggestions to how to get this info?